# Initializing and creating a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, creation

I have experimented with different solutions (including several
discussed on stackoverflow and the R help thread) for a couple of days.
None has produced a good solution. Hence this posting.

I need to create a data frame

```
df <- as.data.frame (matrix (nrow = 3470, ncol = 22,000)
```

The first 3 columns are character / string data. rest are numerical data. The mixed mode screwed up this approach.

```
df <- data.frame (c1 = char(22,000), c2 = char(22,000), c3 = char(22,000), .....)
```

Is there any way to set columns 4 to 22,000 as numeric in this solution? (then I can use colnames (df) to set the real names).

While initializing data frames with something like

```
 df <- data.frame (c1 = char(22,000), c2 = char(22,000), c3 = char(22,000), .....)
```

is there a mechanism for using something like rep to declare that c4 to c22,000 are
numeric?

Thank you very much. (I know initializing data frame has been discussed several
times. I tried several approaches, yet to find a good solution). Hence this post to
a topic that has been beaten to death.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got that syntax from. First, don't use commas as thousands separators; that's fine for humans, but not for computers. Second, the function to create a character vector is `character(n)`, not `char(n)`. Third, the arguments to `data.frame` are the *columns* you want in your data frame, not the rows, so you probably want 3470, not 22000. Finally, the equivalent function for a numeric vector is `numeric(n)`.

```
df <- data.frame(
    c1 = character(3470),
    c2 = character(3470),
    c3 = character(3470),
    n1 = numeric(3470),
    ...)
```

If you really have 22000 columns, you can do it by passing a matrix which will be converted into multiple columns:

```
df <- data.frame(
    c1 = character(3470),
    c2 = character(3470),
    c3 = character(3470),
    n = matrix(0, nrow=3470, ncol=21997))
```